# Ruby Heroku deployment failing: This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18. How can I upgrade my ruby version and make the deployment succeed?

Tags: ruby, heroku

**What is the most efficient way of upgrading Ruby on Mac OS High Sierra?**

I am trying to deploy my simple Ruby app onto Heroku.

I am running the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
18:11 $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 97, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (82/82), done.
Writing objects: 100% (97/97), 22.59 KiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 97 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to 
handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:                         Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:                         See 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry- 
delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external- 
1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.3.tgz -s -o - | tar 
zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry- 
delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external- 
1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.3.tgz -s -o - | tar 
zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote:
remote:  !
```

> ```
> remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.3
> remote:  !
> remote:  !     This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18. The 
> minimum supported version
> remote:  !     of Ruby on the Heroku-18 stack can found at:
> remote:  !
> ```

```
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported- 
runtimes
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to morning-plains-67699.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/morning-plains-67699.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receivehook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/morning-plains- 
67699.git'
```

Comment: might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305305/heroku-is-not-using-the-ruby-version-mentioned-in-gemfile

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear. Update your application to a newer, up-to-date Ruby version and retry.

Comment: I have done this using RVM but I still get the same error.

Comment: You can downgrade heroku stack to solve this issue. Solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354444/how-can-i-solve-this-trouble-to-deploy-a-rails-app-to-heroku?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't support Ruby 2.3.3

> Heroku supports the following Ruby versions and the associated Rubygems. A supported version means that you can expect our tools and platform to work with a given version. It also means you can receive technical support. Here are our supported Ruby versions:
>
> #### MRI:
>
> - 2.4.5 : patchlevel 335, Rubygems: 2.6.14.3
> - 2.5.3: patchlevel 105, Rubygems: 2.7.6
> - 2.6.0: patchlevel 0, Rubygems: 3.0.1

[Read at Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes)

Also read information [how to specify Ruby version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions).

Comment: I have updated to version 2.6.0, updated my gemfile, regenerated the gemlock file and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you make commit after this operations?

Comment: No ... I will try pushing to heroku after doing a commit.

Comment: Did the commit help?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest version of ruby in this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes

then run the latest one `rvm install ruby-2.4.6`

type `ruby -v` in the terminal, you should see ruby 2.4.6.

If it still shows you ruby 2.0., run `rvm use ruby-2.4.6 --default`.

Change the ruby version in your gem file then bundle

This solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or similar error. In my case I did check the branches of the remote , git remote show heroku.

I had a branch main , but no a master , so I made a git checkout

```
git checkout -b main
```

And then

```
git push heroku main
```

Everything was resolved.